# Unable to import sendgrid into GAE application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendgrid

I have a GAE application that I want to integrate with Sendgrid. I've followed the instructions (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid) on how to install Sendgrid and everything works fine in my local dev environment.

However, when I push my application to GAE and run it, I immediately receive the following 500 Server Error:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

Even with debug on, that's all I get. But digging into the logs at GAE I can see the source of the problem:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py",
>   line 240, in Handle
>       handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())   File
>   "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py",
>   line 299, in _LoadHandler
>       handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)   File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py",
>   line 85, in LoadObject
>       obj = ____import____(path[0])   File "/base/data/home/apps/....wsgi_app.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       import sendgrid   File "/base/data/home/apps/..../sendgrid/____init____.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from .client import SendGridAPIClient   File "/base/data/home/apps/..../sendgrid/client.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import python_http_client ImportError: No module named python_http_client

So I went into sendgrid/client.py and commented out the following line of code...

```
import python_http_client
```

Once I do that, I can run my app without receiving the 500 Server Error but the test email I tried to send wasn't delivered (although I didn't receive any error messages when trying to initiate it).

It doesn't seem right that I need to comment out a line of the Sendgrid code to make the import work and I can't figure out why others that are running Sendgrid with Python and GAE aren't having the same problem. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

`sendgrid` does need `python_http_client`, which Sendgrid itself maintains at https://github.com/sendgrid/python-http-client -- just copy the few files in directory https://github.com/sendgrid/python-http-client/tree/master/python_http_client to a directory named python_http_client, making the latter a sibling of the sendgrid directory. I'm not sure why the online docs don't mention that -- I'll work to get it fixed, but meanwhile I hope this workaround lets you get started.

Comment: The instructions recommend to install sendgrid through pip install sendgrid. This should take care of the dependencies, I guess this is the reason this step is not included...

Comment: @dyeray, that works on your local `dev_appserver`, but it can't work on App Engine proper -- you cannot run `pip` there! We're working to fix the docs (hopefully including proper use of https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring which is missing from that part of the docs, too -- not a must but strongly recommended).

Comment: @AlexMartelli just need to pip --target into the local directory to have it as part of the GAE project. Then it will upload automatically when doing deploy